# Ansible Cross Account S3 bucket object lookup and download

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, ansible

I have a S3 bucket in account-a. I have a playbook in account-b which has a task like below

```
---
- name: Configure App Front End on localhost
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  become: true
  vars_files:
    - ./vars.yml
  tasks:
    - name: Download application deployment tar file
      aws_s3:
        bucket:  "{{ varBucketName }}"
        object: s3://{{ varBucketName }}/application/nodejs/dev-v{{ varArtefactVersion }}.tar
        dest: ./dev-v{{ varArtefactVersion }}.tar
        mode: get
```

varBucketName and varArtefactVersion are passed from vars.yml which is in the same level as the playbook is.

This playbook would fail as I am trying to download from account-b an object in S3 bucket in account-a.

Can someone point me on the additional steps/tasks involved for this cross account lookup please.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You must enable cross account access between these buckets before trying to copy the data.

Here's for your quick reference https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cross-account-access-s3/

Comment: Thank you Atul Sharma. Cross account access do exists. If I run a AWS CLI via Jenkins in account-a to download from account-b, it succeeds. What I am missing in the playbook may be extra tasks or keys that helps the playbook to understand from which account the bucket/object need to be looked upon. That is what I am trying to understand with regard to the playbook